# how to list a specified function in R?

Tags: r

in my console:

?nrow

```
Help on topic 'nrow' was found in the following packages:

The number of rows/columns of an array-like object
    (in package BiocGenerics in library C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library)
The Number of Rows/Columns of an Array
    (in package base in library C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.2/library)
```

question 1:
how can i do if i want nrow function in  package `BiocGenerics` ,that is to say :
i want to get only one result .

```
The number of rows/columns of an array-like object
    (in package BiocGenerics in library C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library)
```

question2:
there is no `C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.2/library`  in my computer,why i get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) You can look at a function from a specific package using the `::` operator, which essentially means "from". Try:

```
? BiocGenerics::nrow
```

(2) That directory must exist on your computer because that is where R is. Keep in mind that the `~` is path-shortening symbol...Try looking for the directory returned by the following:

```
.libPaths()
```

Answer (score 0):

`?` is a shortcut for the function `help`.

The function `help` has a package argument, so you can use

`help('nrow', package='BiocGenerics')`

and this will return the results you wish to have.